# networking system call multiplexing on x86 but not on x64

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I was [reading an article](http://jkukunas.blogspot.in/2010/05/x86-linux-networking-system-calls.html) on how networking related system calls are made on x86 and I saw that the calls were multiplexed through a single system call "socketcall". The reason for this additional level of hierarchy seems to be to conserve system call numbers.

Taking a quick look at x64, this does not seem to be the case. Why is this so? Each register in an x86 processor is 32 bits long and should not have trouble storing bigger values for system call numbers; so what is the reason for socketcall not being implemented on x64?

Answer (score 0):

Pure speculation, but on some architectures with a small number of registers like x86, functions beyond a certain number of parameters cannot efficiently pass all of the parameters directly into registers (for x86 this is about 6). For example, sendto and recvfrom take 6 + 1 for the syscall number.  At this point it is more efficient to pass a pointer to an array of longs and as for the others with parameters less than the threshold I am guessing it was a matter of convenience and code sharing between related function.